# Does metamask is necessary for dapp?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, metamask

Does metamask is necessary for communicating with DApps in ethereum network? if no then what is the another way to interact with the Smart Contract ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not required but very handful to start working with [Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/) network and smart contracts using MetaMask.

If you want to start working with [Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/) directly you can use [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) project. This library is very powerful and allows you work with blockchains. For java apps you can use [web3j](https://web3j.io/) project. Checkout theirs [GitHub](https://github.com/web3j/web3j) page.

Answer (score 1):

Metamask is an easy way for you to connect to localnet, testnet or even mainnet. Though its not the only solution for your to operate your dapp.

1. For development purposes you can use Truffle with ganache
2. You can use Infura directly
3. Use geth or parity.
4. I found this one interesting, but use with caution as its only in alpha currently i.e., [Mascara](https://github.com/MetaMask/mascara)